Задача с созданием интерфейса Logger
Вот задача:


Создайте интерфейс Logger с методом Log, который будет записывать сообщение в журнал.
Создайте пользовательский тип LogLevel типа string, сделайте константные значения типа LogLevel со значениями Error и Info.
Создайте структуру Log с полем LogLevel.
Реализуйте метод Log c параметром типа string (текст ошибки), который в зависимости от текущего LogLevel выводит сообщение "ERROR: текст ошибки" или "INFO: текст ошибки".


Есть моё решение:
package main

import "fmt"

type Logger interface {
    Log()
}

type LogLevel string
const FlagF LogLevel = "Error"
const FlagI LogLevel = "Info"

type Log struct {
    Level LogLevel
}

func (l Log) Log(s string) {
    if l.Level == FlagF {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %s", s)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("INFO: %s", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    errorLog := &Log{Level: Error}
    errorLog.Log("This is an error message")
}

Но при выполнении выдаётся ошибка:

undefined: Error в функции main при объявлении структуры errorLog


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как задать хороший вопрос. начните с формулировки заголовка вопроса, например.

Логичный вопрос — что такое Error? В показанном вами коде нет ничего, что имело бы такое имя

Ааааа, я понял, спасибо. Я изначально думал, что полю Level передается строка "Error", а там передается значение константы Error

Если бы в errorLog := &Log{Level: Error} ввод был errorLog := &Log{Level: "Error"} тогда все было бы норм, а так исправления:
package main

import "fmt"

type Logger interface {
    Log()
}

type LogLevel string

const Error LogLevel = "Error"
const Info LogLevel = "Info"

type Log struct {
    Level LogLevel
}

func (l Log) Log(s string) {
    if l.Level == Error {
        fmt.Printf("ERROR: %s", s)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("INFO: %s", s)
    }
}

func main() {
    errorLog := &Log{Level: Error}
    errorLog.Log("This is an error message")
}


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]
